# Rails-code changed on production server, but no changes on browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5, production-environment

I have added some code and pushed it on my git account and also take pull it on server, and also run command
 `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` 
and restarted `nginx` server many times. 
While editing the code using `nano` command on server, it shows updated.

Comment: it should work, may be clear you cache!

Comment: Have you tried restarting or reloading the app server (Puma / Passanger / Unicorn) ?

Comment: How to restart passanger ?

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `rails` + `nginx` + `passenger`, you can enter the server rails app root and use `touch tmp/restart.txt` to restart the rails app.  so changes on browser.

reference: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/restart_app.html#restart-txt